# Where to add svg in Magento to set allowed extension?

Tags: php, magento, svg

Whenever I am trying to upload an svg image file in products it keeps saying "Disallowed file type". I've already added the file extension like this:

```
$uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png','svg'));
```

in:

- Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Attribute/Backend/Media.php
- Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/GalleryController.php
- Mage/Catalog/Model/Category/Attribute/Backend/Image.php

Do I need to add 'svg' in other than those 3 core files also?

My Magento ver. is 1.9.2.4.